# Should I re-ask a very old question?

Tags: discussion, questions, outdated-information

I just searched for `python numpy array decimal` and the first result that Google shows is:

[numpy array with dtype Decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7770870/1391441)

The answers there are 11 years old. I have the exact same question so it is most definitely a duplicate, but it is very possible that something has changed in the past decade.

What should I do?

Comment: Try the answers, if they work, then great! If not, then create a bounty.

Comment: A bounty seems reasonable

Comment: the highehst voted answers look like they are still valid

Comment: `Decimal` isn't a native machine type, so there isn't anything that numpy can do with it. I very, very much doubt this is going to ever change.

Comment: There are probably 10s or 100s of low-scored duplicates to this question among the [100,707 NumPy questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy). Some of the answers to those may be up-to-date. Do cast close votes or at least leave comments to point towards the canonical question.

Comment: [A lead](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html#user-defined-data-types).

Comment: [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750012/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-complex-number-in-numpy-with-the-accuracy-of-a-decimal).

Comment: Why is the answers out of date? Is an answer that 2+2 from 500 years ago outdated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a general case, if you believe that the answers are outdated you could do couple of things

- if you know a better answer that is absolutely different,  you could post your answer
- if a new answer would be only slightly different, consider editing an existing one to include relevant approach
- if you are afraid that this answer would stay at the bottom, you could then start a bounty. Keep in mind that minimal bounty amount is not 50 but 100 when a question has your answer already.
- if you don't know an answer you could just start a bounty right away. There's a specific bounty reason that is reserved for such cases:

  [image]

The bounty is the only correct way to go in this case, if you don't know an answer. It's discouraged to post a duplicate question with a purpose to refresh the topic.

Comment: And how would a User with <50-Rep or <100-Rep do...? With <50-Rep, they can't start a Bounty, they can't even comment... With <100-Rep, they can just start the Bounty, and they further lose the ability to comment..., until they reach 50-Rep again...

Comment: @chiv well, the solution is go and gain some rep :)